# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) in angular 6 application

Tags: json, angular

I have searched about it in google, Yes I understood that am receiving `context/type:text/html` not `application/json`,but I didn't get how to solve this issue. when I trying to hit the api of third party user from my local server , am getting this error. Please check the screenshot of this error.

[image]

[image]

service.ts

```
    export class VamosysService {
    constructor(private _http:Http){}

    getVechicalLocations():Observable<any[]>{
         return this._http.get(API_URL)
                         .pipe(map((response:Response)=<any[]>response.json()));

}
```

component.ts

```
export class VamosysComponent implements OnInit {

  vechicalLocation:any[];

  constructor(private _vamoService:VamosysService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  this._vamoService.getVechicalLocations()
                        .subscribe((data) => this.vechicalLocation = data);
  }



}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is screenshot ?

Comment: You are getting status 302, The problem is with you'r server (i guess) . you'r server should return status 200 ( ok ) to you'r client.

Comment: if you post [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) of you'r code i can help you more :)

Comment: so its not a problem from client side right.

Comment: Ya, I will try to put my code in #stackblitz

Comment: As long as you are not getting http status 200 from server YES. when you'r server is returning 200 and still things are not going good , that means you'r client has some problem.

Comment: I have just added my code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/vamosys-angular6  . Please check it out. Thanks

Comment: @AtmanSan http://gpsvts.net/gps/public/getVehicleLocations does not return any data. so i used some test api to check get request. then it is working fine the problem with http://gpsvts.net/gps/public/getVehicleLocations it is not working :).  with that change your code is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/vamosys-angular6-iqpblv?file=src/app/vamosys/vamosys.component.ts.  And also try to use HttpClient Modue than old Http :)

Comment: Okay. Thank you I will check it.

Comment: @AtmanSan i updated my answer also you could find there working demo as well :)

Comment: @stack fan - sure! I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: @stack fan - I have doubt , http://gpsvts.net/gps/public/getVehicleLocations this api call can access only after login of this url http://gpsvts.net/gps/public/login. so,is this problem that I couldnt access that api from my localhost:4000?

Comment: I think I should go with Xampp server to make access of api call right?.. if so how can I achive this with xampp server... please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry i didn't work with **gpsvts** but according to there [api](http://gpsvts.net/gps/public/apiAcess) you have to pass some extra parameters this is their sample api call   `http://<domainname>/apiMobile/getVehicleLocations?apiKey=ndwlraqfxujojrmktvzg& userId=DEMO&groupId=DEMO` . see the **3. Get Live Locations** in their [api](http://gpsvts.net/gps/public/apiAcess)

Comment: And also see this **Note:** "An apiKey, used to indicate whether the invoker is authorized. Reference to 4.1 for acquiring the token.The apiKey should only be used within your server side code, otherwise it will not work."

Comment: @stackfan- Thanks for helped on this. Due to cant access this api without server side coding.. finally am gonna with hard code of array of jsonObject - my main task is UI part of this jsonobject.

Comment: @AtmanSan great! if you don't mind and my answer help to solve your problem in UI level could you please accept it as a answer

Comment: Ya sure and also sorry for till now not accepted your answer. Thanks again. God bless you bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your <kbd>[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vamosys-angular6)</kbd>. The [api](http://gpsvts.net/gps/public/getVehicleLocations) that you have used is not working properly. If it changed to working `get` `api` call it is working properly. <kbd>[WORKING demo with different test `api` call](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vamosys-angular6-iqpblv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvamosys%2Fvamosys.service.ts).</kbd>

and instead of using **`Http`** I'm suggesting you to use [**HttpClient**](https://angular.io/guide/http) with additional benefits.

> The HttpClient in @angular/common/http offers a simplified client HTTP
>   API for Angular applications that rests on the XMLHttpRequest
>   interface exposed by browsers. Additional benefits of HttpClient
>   include testability features, typed request and response objects,
>   request and response interception, Observable apis, and streamlined
>   error handling.

Then you no need explicitly parsed into `json` inside `map`. And also it will return a observable type. You could just consume the return `json` after subscribe to it.

Before you can use the `HttpClient`, you need to import the Angular `HttpClientModule` (into root `AppModule`).

**Sample `AppModule`  code:**

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then import `HttpClient` inside your **`VamosysService`**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Try to use **`getVechicalLocations()`** like below

```
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getVechicalLocations(){
         return this._http.get(API_URL);

    }
```

Hope this helps to you!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `HttpModule` which is **deprecated** you should use **[HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)** instead
In new `HttpClientModule` JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed using `res.json()`
**Service**

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        export class VamosysService {
        constructor(private _httpc:HttpClient){}

        getVechicalLocations():Observable<any[]>{
             return this._httpc.get(API_URL);}
```

**Component**

```
 export class VamosysComponent implements OnInit {

      public vechicalLocation=[];

      constructor(private _vamoService:VamosysService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
      this._vamoService.getVechicalLocations()
                            .subscribe((data) => this.vechicalLocation=data);
      }}
```

In Case if you are Requesting non-JSON data
you can use the `responseType` property.

```
getVechicalLocations():Observable<any[]>{
                 return this._httpc.get(API_URL,{ responseType: 'text' });}
```

response type could be `responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error when getting a string back from the response. My error was:

> error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttp…, text: "We've just sent you an email to reset your password."}

And I don't have control over the actual response. However, I found [this in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data) which specifically sets that you can be expecting non-JSON responses. So you would have something like

```
return this._http.get(API_URL, {responseType: 'text'})        // Notice the additional parameter here
    .pipe(map((response:Response)=<any[]>response.json()));
```

I notice you're also specifically parsing json after though, so it would be depending on the actual response on how you want to handle it.